# Layout view for a model is not working -- Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, models

I'd appreciate any pointers into what may be going wrong:

```
# Controller
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
@users = User.all
end

# View

    <table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>UID</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
</tr>

<% for user in @users %>
<tr>
  <td> <%= user.name %> </td>
  <td> <%= user.uid %> </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>   

# Model - generated using: generate model :name :uid
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :uid
end
```

That's what I get for "`www.myWebAdress.com/users`"

```
Name UID
```

Why is the users list missing? Rails console shows three users.

---

Here is the source file of :www.myWebAdress.com/user generated by "show source"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body  >

</br>
</br>

<div class="container">
</br>
</br>
  <div class="content" align="center">

</br>
</br>

</br>
</br>
   <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>UID</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>

   </table>   
  </div>

</div>


<footer>

</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure this controller is right? You have two `def index` in it. And what about the model? Shouldn't be `:uid` instead of `:kid`?

Comment: I'm sorry for my sloppiness. They are both typos. I made error in cutting and pasting from my code. I still don't know why my code is not working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: BTW, I did reedit the code above!

Comment: There is nothing in your view to imply the index action (nothing dynamic, so why would nothing that would cause you to expect a listing as an output.)

Comment: Thanks Joshua for your comment. I thought that it was implicit through the rails framework. Isn't that true? If not how can I be explicit about it? The view is at app/views/users/index.html.erb.

Comment: Please provide the exact source that it generates. "Show source" in your browser. Than we will see if it does not proceed the whole block or if the user values are just blank.

Comment: Are your console and the server process running with the same RAILS_ENV?

Comment: Frederick, They are using the same environment (development). Jan, Here is the source:--------------------------------------------------

Comment: @JanMinárik It seems like it does not proceed the whole block!

Comment: Are you sure your route is right? If you put any static content on your view, is it changing on the result?

Comment: What does it happen when you put a `<% @users = User.all %>` at the beginning of your view?

Comment: *** New information. I just found out that it works OK using the local rails server: http://localhost:3000/users. It does not work on the Heroku server. I'm currently trying to debug this. Any pointers. Thanks again @YuriAlbuquerque!!

Comment: I just found out in the Heroku documents: "Heroku uses PostgreSQL as its default database. Heroku does not support SQLite or MySQL"  OOPs!!

Comment: Uh... this may be caused from the fact that there are three different databases for Rails applications. One for tests, one for development, one for production. I think you were trying to access data from development on the production database.

Comment: It was both a development environment. I was not set up to use Sqlite3 on Heroku because Heroku does not support Sqlite3 period. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the cause, but can you try replacing

```
<% for user in @users %>
```

with

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
```

Comment: I tried that, I still have the same problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would try adding `puts @users.inspect` in your controller and see what the output is. Also can you post the output in the console where you see 3 users?

Comment: When I do rails console and type User.all, I see three users. I'll try @users.inspect and let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: I can also see three users using SQLite Database Browser.

Comment: I get a blank square quotes. I added <%= @users.inspect %> to the view file.

Comment: That's interesting. The only thing I can think of is somehow your rails app is not hitting the same db as the console. (Not sure how).. can you double-check the config?

Comment: Thanks. I'll check! What shall I look for?

Comment: database config (database.yml), RAILS_ENV.. I really can't think of anything else. For all I know, this track of debugging may be a red herring and the problem might be something entirely unrelated. :(

Comment: Thanks Adnan! I can't find anything wrong. It all checks out. That is puzzling! Thanks for your help anyway. If you have other ideas to explore, I'd appreciate a ping!!

Comment: ***** New information. I just found out that it works OK using the local rails server: localhost:3000/users. It does not work on the Heroku server. I'm currently trying to debug this. Any pointers. Thanks again Adnan!

Comment: Adnan, I just found out in the Heroku documents: "Heroku uses PostgreSQL as its default database. Heroku does not support SQLite or MySQL" OOPs!!

Comment: Oh.. that's good to know. Thanks. I've personally never used Heroku, for development environment, so I was assuming localhost. Thanks for posting your resolution.

Comment: Thanks Adnan! I'd like to keep in touch. Best!